# Stack overflow occurs if I call an assembler routine too many times

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-overflow, intel-fortran, stdcall

I pruned everything to the min to show this problem

In Compaq Visual Fortran I write

```
    Do 1 I =1,N
    CALL SUBNAM(A,B,100)
1   CONTINUE
```

If "SUBNAM" is  any routine written in Fortran , the DO  loop count N  can be as big as you like. N=100000 is no problem.

If SUBNAM  is an assembler (Goasm) routine, even as simple as

```
_SUBNAM@12:  Push Ecx
             Pop  Ecx
             Ret
```

then N greater than about 86000 gives stack overflow.
Even though the stack pointer is NOT  corrupted!

If the assembler routine is only

```
_SUBNAM@12: RET
```

I do not get stack overflow with N as high as 100000

WTF???

Information: Fortran "decorates" subroutine names with a leading underscore and @mm at the end where mm is 4 times the number of arguments. This is the amount of stack in bytes it uses for pushing argument addresses. It is the calling program's responsibility to clear up the stack upon being returned to. I have peeked at the stack before and after the call to SUBNAM  and the stack pointer does return to the pre-Call value.

I have disabled all traceback compiler options in case debugging info was being crested at every call. It may be, and maybe a Fortran  SUBNAM  includes code to erase the traceback info that the call to it created?

Does the Pentium processor have another stack that could be overflowing, other than ESP?

Comment: stdcall is a callee-pops convention.  The `@12` means you should be using `ret 12` because that's how much the caller expects this function to move ESP by.

Comment: BTW, if you look at the compiler-generated asm for the function that doesn't break, you'll see the `ret 12` there.

Comment: You are dead right! Thanks. I have mixed assembler and Fortran for years without knowing that, and never had problems until now, due to playing with very large do loop count. Ret 12 indeed solved the probblem.  Don't know why , when I peeked the stackpounter value, that I didn't see it growing though!

Comment: I'm really surprised your code hasn't broken before; returning with ESP pointing to the wrong place will break the caller's access to its local vars, unless you compile with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or equivalent so those accesses are relative to EBP.  Maybe for 32-bit Windows, that's the default even with optimization enabled?  (Unlike for Linux).